# What does a water pressure regulator look like?

Tags: water-pressure

The water pressure in my flat has been getting lower and lower.

It is my understanding that checking the pressure regulator is a good first step, but I am unsure about what to look for.

Is it that thing?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Bonus question: if it is it, how would you add a manometer to this installation?

Comment: Probably obvious, but before touching anything water-related, like the pressure regulator, do find the closest upstream isolation valve and be sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a faucet with a hose bibb on it, a faucet like those used in a laundry tub, you could go to a big box store or hardware store and purchase a threaded on pressure gauge to check the existing water pressure. I have one and use it a couple times a year to check my in-coming pressure. This will let you know just what the pressure is.

Yes, that looks like a simple water regulating valve that adjusts the in-coming water pressure. Adjustments of the pressure higher or lower are with a screw driver.